# Downloading images to show in table view cells: who should perform the networking task?

Tags: ios, uitableview, concurrency, uiviewcontroller, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I have found examples showing two different ways of solving this scenario:

**Option A: responsible for networking to be the `UITableViewController`**

It would be something like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard results.count > 0 else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyCell.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCell

    imageProvider.getImage(imageUrl: imageUrl, completion: {[weak self] (image, error) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       if error == nil && image != nil {
            if let updateCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyCell {
               updateCell.updateImage(image!)
            }
       } 
    }
})
    return myCell
}
```

where `imageProvider.getImage` has an `URLSessionDownloadTask` and calls `let task = session.downloadTask()` and `task.resume()`.

**Option B: responsible for networking to be the `UITableViewCell`**

I have seen an example similar to this:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

// Several IBOutlets

static let cellIdentifier = "myCell"
let imageProvider = ImageProvider()

var model: MyModel? {
   willSet {
      activityIndicator.startAnimating()
      configureImage(showImage: false, showActivity: true)
   }
   didSet {
      guard let modelUrlStr = model?.imageUrlStr, let imageUrl = URL(string: modelUrlStr) else {
         activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
         configureImage(showImage: false, showActivity: false)
         return
   }

   imageProvider.getImage(imageUrl: imageUrl, completion: {[weak self] (image, error) in
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
          guard error == nil else {
              self?.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
              self?.configureImage(showImage: false,  showActivity: false)
              return
          }

          self?.imageView.image = image
          self?.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
          self?.configureImage(showCoverImage: true, showActivity: false)
       }
   })
}
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
  super.awakeFromNib()
  configureImage(showCoverImage: false, showActivity: false)
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
  super.prepareForReuse()
  model = nil
}

private func configureImage(showImage: Bool, showActivity: Bool) {
  // Update image view
} 
}
```

Here, `imageProvider.getImage` also has an `URLSessionDownloadTask` and calls `let task = session.downloadTask()` and `task.resume()`.
On the other hand, in this approach, I think that the cell shouldn't have a reference to the model object, but it is appropriate to do the networking task in the cell?

**Additional considerations:**

- I need the N images I need to download, one per each cell that is shown, to be downloaded concurrently.
- I also need to be able to cancel all the downloads that could be in progress if the user wants to stop them.

Which option/approach should I go for? (Could be maybe one different from these)

Comment: second approach is the best & also try to save images in the cache for better performance. Look at this tutprial https://videos.raywenderlich.com/courses/74-practical-instruments/lessons/3  download the code available on bottom of page

Comment: @Gagan_iOS Thanks, I'll check that